# The call is ambiguous between the following methode or properties: 'SGSClient.onSend(System.IAsyncResult)' and SGSClient.OnSend(System.IAsyncResult)'

Tags: c#

the call is ambiguous between the following  methode or properties: `'SGSClient.onSend(System.IAsyncResult)'` and `SGSClient.OnSend(System.IAsyncResult)'`

```
clientSocket.BeginSendTo(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, epServer,  new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);
```

Comment: Is that the *exact* error message? It seems unlikely that the C# compiler would become case-insensitive. Can you post a short but complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: What is the question? The call is ambiguous. So what?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have declared the InitializeComponent method in two places in your class, probably one in each partial class. Try searching in all files for InitializeComponent in Visual Studio and I'm guessing that the results will list two places where it is declared. Delete one and the error will disappear.